# Sending an SMS/iMessage programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, sms, imessage, messageui

I’ve seen many things that mention using MessageUI Framework for COMPOSING messages, but is there a way to automate SENDING it in Swift? Perhaps even allowing my code to run once the Send Button is pressed, then I call the actual method to send it.

Comment: No. It requires user action. This allow to avoid undesired spam. You need to use a third party code (with server, etc. and it may costs money, because it's SMS, and phone companies charge it).

Answer (score 3):

You can't just send a message without user's confirmation, but you can present the `MFMessageComposeViewController` at any time you want.

```
import MessageUI

func sendSMS(with text: String) {
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageComposeViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageComposeViewController.body = text
        present(messageComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```